# How to combine SingleChildScrollView and vertical carousel?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
CarouselSlider(
  options: CarouselOptions(
    autoPlay: false,
    enableInfiniteScroll: false,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    enlargeCenterPage: false,
    viewportFraction: 1,
    initialPage: 0,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    pageSnapping: false,
    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
      setState(() {
        _currentSlider = index;
      });
    }),
  items: images.map((e) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Image.memory(
            e,
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
  }).toList(),
  carouselController: _controller,
  ),
```

I combined SingleChildScrollView and CarouselSlider. But when I scroll down image, SingleChildScrollView intercept to move next image.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean that the Carousel intercepts it ?

Comment: I mean only scroll of SingleChildScrollView work, but scroll of Carousel not work.

Comment: you can disable scroll physics for SingleChildScrollView